# NotImplementedError: `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for unbuilt Model subclasses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
##############################################################

traindata = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

input = traindata.flow_from_directory('VS/train')

    modelo = tf.keras.Sequential()
    modelo.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 
 activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
    modelo.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    modelo.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
    modelo.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
    modelo.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

modelo.fit_generator(input, epochs=1)
```

However, I am getting this error:

So by running the code below I get this error

```
NotImplementedError: `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for unbuilt Model subclasses
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't specify the `input_shape` in the first layer, so the model is not fully defined. This process has not been implemented with `fit_generator`, so you should fully define the model with the initial `input_shape`.